# ENS look up an address

Tags: ens

How do I resolve an ENS name to an address?

Hopefully with a pretty interface, something my grandmom can use.

Answer (score 1):

MyEtherWallet offers a simple lookup: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#ens

Comment: When I search susquares.eth I get a resolved address of 0x. However I expected this transaction to set the resolved address https://etherscan.io/tx/0x887ac5a17a2bccd809b08fb24256f45b3f1cfd50dc17e4bde0af44a7737e542e. Can I be confident in the result of that ENS lookup?